# Need help on Oracle 10g express edition

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-xe, oracle-type

I got error "ora-03001: unimplemented feature" when I try to insert a record on table below. I've  searched all night, still no luck. I'm using Oracle10g express edition.

```
create or replace type MajorsType As varray(20) of varchar2(10);

create or replace type studenttype as object (
stuID varchar2(5),
lastName varchar2(15),
firstName varchar2(12),
majors MajorsType)
INSTANTIABLE
NOT FINAL;

create table Student of StudentType (
constraint student_stuID_pk PRIMARY KEY(stuID));

INSERT INTO student values StudentType ('S999', 'Smith', 'John', MajorsType('Math', 'Accounting'));
```

Comment: Why are you using the expression edition when you can easily download the full edition?

Comment: I'm new to this thing, and I think express edition is free.

Comment: the full version is free for the purposes of self-education.  The license applied to commercial usage.

Comment: Not that using XE is relevant to the error in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple syntax error: the VALUES clause requires everything to be wrapped in parentheses:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO student
  2  values ( StudentType ('S999', 'Smith', 'John', MajorsType('Math', 'Accounting')))
  3  /

1 row created.

SQL>
```

This applies whether we're passing in several scalar values or a single type.

---

The one case when it doesn't apply is an insert in PL/SQL using a RECORD type.  Which is not relevant to your situation, but I'm mentioning it for completeness.

Inserting a RECORD variable would look something like this

```
declare
    r23 t23%rowtype;  -- record declaration
begin
    r23.id := 1;
    r23.created := sysdate;
    -- insert using record variable
    insert into t23
    values r23; 
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm newbie for Oracle database stuff. I usually use phpMyAdmin with mySQL.

Comment: +1 for the information about inserting into a RECORD. Always hard to find information about that as it's not documented quite well enough